# How can I delete cart item on index using Redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I want to delete a product I click on inside my cart using Redux. I am able to delete a product with "pop" but it obviously deletes the last item on the list instead of the one I click on. Each product has it's own price that I want to subtract from the total as well. The product and it's price have the same index in the products list and shoePrice list.

```
import {createSlice} from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const cartSlice = createSlice({
    name:"cart",
    initialState:{
        products: [], 
        quantity: 0,
        total: 0,
        shoePrice: [], 
},

reducers:{
    addProduct:(state, action)=>{
        state.quantity += 1;
        state.products.push(action.payload);
        state.shoePrice.push(action.payload.price);
        state.total += action.payload.price;
    },

    removeProduct:(state, action)=>{
        if(state.quantity > 0) {
            state.quantity -= 1;
            state.total = state.total - state.shoePrice.pop(1);
            state.products.pop(1);
        }
    },
  },
});

export const {addProduct, removeProduct} = cartSlice.actions
export default cartSlice.reducer;
```

Comment: You can use `array.filter` or slice, https://jaketrent.com/post/remove-array-element-without-mutating

Comment: You can also use `array.splice(index, 1)` to remove an element in a specific `index`.  It will mutate the state but it shouldn't be a problem with redux toolkit. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove the product from array using index:

`state.products.splice(index, 1)`

If you want to just pop the last added product:

```
state.products.splice(state.products.length-1, 1)
```